# Get event and resources by selecting calendar week on full calendar timeline view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is there any builtin function to get on click event on Calendar week row in fullcalendar? I would like to get information of event and resources with respect to its weeks.
thanks,

Update:

Now i am able to click on header (date and week) and get clicked date and first day of week. **Next step should be to print resources and its events on console, anyone have any idea???** following are the code for the on click event on

line number 2623 on scheduler.js

class="fc-cell-text" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="customOnclick(\'' + cell.dateData + '\')"

```
function customOnclick(date,resourceObj) {
console.log('i just clicked on ' + date +'' +resourceObj);
if (typeof customSchedulerOnclickHandler === 'function') {
    customSchedulerOnclickHandler(date);
}}
```